# Changing trains at Firenze S.M.N. train station - how fast can it be done?

Tags: italy, train-stations, florence

We are traveling by train (already reserved) from Rome to Lucca in a couple of weeks with a train change at Firenze S.M.N.

Itinerary:
Rome Termini -> Firenze S.M.N. : **Arrives @ 11:50** (Frecciarossa 9520)

Firenze S. M. Novella -> Lucca : **Depart @ 12:10** (Regionale 3056)

I just looked at the tickets and the time between the 2 trains will be on the short side. The station looks to be small.

How easy/fast is it to go from the high speed train to the Regionale trains?

Assuming we stand at the door with luggage and are ready to *run like hell* between the trains.

Comment: without time or platform information (there are 19 platforms)  would be hard to say. The shown map does not contain the platform numbers. https://www.firenzesantamarianovella.it/en/map/#

Comment: All reasonable connections I can find from Rome to Lucca have at least 19 minutes stay in Firenze S.M.N. You have to provide your connection details and track numbers for anyone to be able to answer your question.

Comment: How short are we talking here?

Comment: Google Maps show that the platform numbers start on the left (2/3) to the right (14/15)

Comment: I updated my posts with more information about the arrival and departure at Firenze SMN.

Comment: I still don't get your question. You have 20 minutes to change trains. Why on earth should you have to *run like hell* to manage that? You will have time for several cups of coffee and/or something to eat in that time.

Comment: because I don't know how large is the station, if tracks are far away from each other, , and if the first train runs late, what would be the minimal time to make a safe transfer between the 2 trains.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Judging by today’s information found [here](https://www.wanderio.com/en/trains/find-train/3056), the train left at platform 6 when it usually leaves at 7.

And judging by the information found [here](https://www.wanderio.com/en/trains/find-train/9520), it arrives at platform 9 and departed from the station 6 minutes late.

Say even if the train is 10 minutes late, you have 10 minutes to walk between 2/3 platforms, **more than enough time**.

Even 13 minutes is plenty of time:

> 13 minutes is plenty if your train arrives on time.

(Source: [Tripadvisor](https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g187895-i68-k3680143-Time_required_to_change_trains_at_Firenze_SMN-Florence_Tuscany.html))

Answer (score 7):

I have been at this station many a times. The important thing to note is the only way to get from one platform to another is at the front. There is no overpass or underground walkway, you need to get to the front where there are no train tracks. You can save a few minutes if you get as close to the front of the train as possible. The station is not wide, the tracks are close. But I wouldn't worry: the entire station is about 250 metres long so it takes perhaps five minutes to walk from one end to the other. (Which you will do if you want to get to the buses on Viale Filippo Strozzi: you need to get to the side of the building past platform 15 where the baggage storage (deposito bagagli) is and walk all the way to the back, there is an exit there and then an elevated walkway leading straight to the buses. This exit is not signed and impossible to find without prior knowledge.)

Answer (score 4):

Thanks all,

The Frecciarossa 9520 train was a little late, but arrived with enough time for us to find the track #3 where the train to Lucca departed.

We will be less stressed on our way back.

Answer (score 3):

Just to add to the other helpful answers there is some extra information on the Man in Seat 61's page on Firenze SMN which may be helpful (https://www.seat61.com/stations/florence-santa-maria-novella.htm). As well as providing a link to the map mentioned in a comment above (https://www.firenzesantamarianovella.it/it/map/) he also provides a few pictures but more importantly

> When connecting between two Trenitalia trains (for example, a Regionale from Siena into a Frecciarossa high-speed train to Rome or Venice) as long as the scheduled connection is over 15 minutes, you are entitled to later onward travel at no charge if a delay means a missed connection.  Online systems will only suggest valid connections.  See Trenitalia staff at the help desk if you need reserved seats on a later train.  However, that does not apply if you were connecting from a Regionale into a privately-run Italo high-speed train as you'd then be using two different companies.